# How to efficiently use a tf.data.Dataset made of ordereddict?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

Using TensorFlow 2.3.1, the code snippet below fails.

```
import tensorflow as tf

url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/creditcard.zip"

tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    origin=url,
    fname='creditcard.zip',
    cache_dir="/tmp/datasets/",
    extract=True)

ds = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    "/tmp/datasets/*.csv",
    batch_size=2048,
    label_name="Class",
    select_columns=["V1","V2","Class"],
    num_rows_for_inference=None,
    shuffle_buffer_size=600,
    ignore_errors=True)

model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="labeling"),
    ],
)

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-2),
    loss="binary_crossentropy", 
)

model.fit(
    ds,
    steps_per_epoch=5,
    epochs=3,
)
```

The error stack is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-c79f80f9d0fd> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(
      2     ds,
      3     steps_per_epoch=5,
      4     epochs=3,
      5 )

[...]

    ValueError: Layer sequential expects 1 inputs, but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(2048, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_1:0' shape=(2048, 1) dtype=float32>]
```

The solution I use so far is

```
def workaround(features, labels):
    return (tf.stack(list(features.values()), axis=1), labels)

model.fit(
    ds.map(workaround),
    steps_per_epoch=5,
    epochs=3,
)
```

My questions to you TF gurus:

- Am I doing the right thing or is there a better solution?
- Performance wise, is that solution viable for a dataset that would not fit in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'am not sure your code can fit the data in memoey or not .

If not , you can change your code like this :

```
import tensorflow as tf

url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/creditcard.zip"
ds = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    "/tmp/datasets/*.csv",
    batch_size=2048,
    label_name="Class",
    select_columns=["V1","V2","Class"],
    num_rows_for_inference=None,
    ignore_errors=True,
    num_epochs = 1,
    shuffle_buffer_size=2048*1000, 
    prefetch_buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
)

input_list = []
for column in ["V1", "V2"]:
    _input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,))
    input_list.append(_input)

concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(name="concat")(input_list)
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu", name="dense", dtype='float64' )(concat)
output_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="labeling", dtype='float64')(dense)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_list, outputs=output_dense)

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-2),
    loss="binary_crossentropy", 
)

model.fit(
    ds,
    steps_per_epoch=5,
    epochs=10,
)
```

Comment: I edited your answer and fixed the code so that it runs. Thank you.

When I fit on that whole, yet rather small, dataset (~250K rows / 30 columns), I obtain the same **average duration per step at 110ms/step**. Not sure this kind of test using one single machine makes any sense.

Based on the limited knowledge I have, I would favor your solution because it is more intelligible & maintainable. The `tf.concat` sounds more hackish to me.

**Any complementary idea/comment will be most welcomed.**